# Canvas animation keeps redrawing previous frames

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I am figuring this one out an unhealthy amount of time for now and I did not found any note for this bug. I started to build a simple HTML Canvas animation in JavaScript. For now I expect the small squares to move. Here is the code (I am also using *babeljs*):

```
class Pod {
  constructor(x,y) {        
    this.posX = x;
    this.posY = y;
    this.velX = getRandomNumber(-5,5);
    this.velY = getRandomNumber(-5,5);    
  }

  getPos() {
    return ([this.posX,this.posY]);
  }

  move() {
    this.posX += this.velX;
    this.posY += this.velY;
  }

  render() {    
    ctx.save();   
    ctx.rect(this.posX,this.posY,3,3);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}
/*the classes end here*/

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var elementsNum = 10;

const stack = new Array(elementsNum);

for(var i = 0; i < elementsNum; i++) {
  stack[i] = new Pod(getRandomNumber(0,500),getRandomNumber(0,500));
}


function run() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for(var i = 0; i < elementsNum; i++) {
    stack[i].move();
    stack[i].render();
  }
  //window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
}


/*helper functions*/
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

After running a cycle of the function *run()*, the small squares (I called them *Pod*s) are rendered. Next cycle starts with clearing the canvas with *ctx.clearRect...* I am resetting the context and start moving and then drawing the *Pod*s from the stack. When I draw the first *Pod*, it will draw all of them and also the previous frame.

Here is the codepen for this particular script: http://codepen.io/erikputz/pen/YNNXqX

(I knowingly commented the requestAnimationFrame, so you need to use the console to call the *run()* function)

Thank you forward for your help.

Comment: Why do you `ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');` in the run when you already have it?

Comment: honestly, I found it on an another pen when I tried to solve the bug. However, it does not change anything. Feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codepen.io/zfrisch/pen/bgazyO

This should solve your issue:

```
render() {    

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(this.posX,this.posY,3,3);
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

}
```

With canvas you need to identify individual shapes through code by using the `beginPath` and `closePath` methods. In certain methods this is innate, like in `fillRect`. Hence the above code could be simplified even more to:

```
render() {    
ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
ctx.fillRect(this.posX,this.posY,3,3);  
}
```

When you're just declaring a shape (`rect`) you need to specify when the path begins and when it is closed, otherwise it will most likely cause issues like the shape-bleeding you had in your original code.

Also, as a tip, you don't need to save state`.save()` / `.restore()` unless you're translating/scaling/rotating/or moving on the canvas element. Filling shapes doesn't apply.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Every documentation I red, they never mentioned that this is necessary for rect shapes. Somehow they always explained it with curves or similar shapes. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @ErikPutz it's no problem!

Comment: closePath is useless for rect, it's just a lineTo last sub-path's first point.